# Why looping twice on string length test

Tags: c#, try-catch, uppercase

I'm working in C# (2013) Windows Forms. My instructor wanted us to ensure that the txtStateInput is upperCase when we hit the calculate button. However when I input a two character string such as "wi" and then hit calculate, it throws the message "enter valid state" and clears out the textbox. When I enter the "wi" in a second time then it works. I can't figure out why this is happening, the code would lead me to believe that it would check to ensure the string in txtStateInput is two characters and then when calculate is clicked it would uppercase the string. I can't figure out why it only works once I enter in the state "wi" a second time.

```
       private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //declare variables.
            int startPop = 0;
            int endPop = 0;
            string Message = "Error";
            decimal Percent = 0.0m;
            string State = "";
            string City = String.Empty;
            int dTimes = 0;

            try
            {
                City = txtCityInput.Text;

                //System Globalization was initialized  so this method works.
                TextInfo myTI = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;
                txtCityInput.Text = myTI.ToTitleCase(City);

                if(txtStateInput.Text.Length != 2)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Enter valid State");
                    txtStateInput.Focus();
                    txtStateInput.SelectAll();
                }

                else
                {
                    State = txtStateInput.Text.ToUpper();
                    txtStateInput.Text = State;

                    if ((int.TryParse(txtStartPopInput.Text, out startPop)) && int.TryParse(txtEndPopInput.Text, out endPop))
                    {
                        if ((startPop > 0) && (endPop > 0))
                        {
                            //if population has decreased.
                            if ((startPop > endPop))
                            {
                                Percent = ((decimal.Parse(endPop.ToString()) - decimal.Parse(startPop.ToString())) / decimal.Parse(startPop.ToString()));
                                Message = "Pop. Decrease of " + Percent.ToString("p");
                            }
                            //if population has increased.
                            if ((startPop < endPop))
                            {
                                Percent = ((decimal.Parse(endPop.ToString()) - decimal.Parse(startPop.ToString())) / decimal.Parse(startPop.ToString()));
                                Message = "Pop. Increase of " + Percent.ToString("p");
                            }
                            //if population has not changed.
                            if ((startPop == endPop))
                            {
                                Percent = ((decimal.Parse(endPop.ToString()) - decimal.Parse(startPop.ToString())) / decimal.Parse(startPop.ToString()));
                                Message = "No Change in Population";
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid population figures.");
                        }
                    }
                if (int.TryParse(txtDisplayTimes.Text, out dTimes))
                {
                    if (dTimes > 0)
                    {
                        lstResults.Items.Clear();
                        int iSum = 0;
                        int iLoopCount = dTimes;

                        //displays the results according to value in txtDisplayTimes.
                        for (iSum = 1; iSum <= iLoopCount; iSum++)
                        {
                            lstResults.Items.Add(Message);
                        }
                    }
                }
                }
            }



            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong.");
            }

        }
```

Comment: How about debugging it line by line and figuring it out as to why it does not work the first time?

Comment: Also make sure to write local variables in camelCase. You should keep the usual style conventions.

Comment: You're doing to much in one go to be able to clearly see what's causing the weird behaviour. Start with `if(txtStateInput.Text.Length != 2) { MessageBox.Show("Enter valid State"); } else { MessageBox.Show("Great!"); }`. If that works, try changing the inside of the else block to `txtStateInput.Text = txtStateInput.Text.ToUpper();` and see if it still works. Continue making very small changes (best case: one line at a time) until you either have it doing exactly what you want all the time or you notice weird behaviour. And if you do, probably (one of) the last change(s) caused it.

Comment: Thank You for the feedback, I'm in (C# Intro) class and the code involving the txtStateInput is something the instructor was using. So I figured I would try to add it to mine.

Comment: Well I figured out what the problem was, unfortunately the txtCityInput was set to clear out the txtStateInput on text change. I can't believe that I was overlooking that piece of information. Thanks bit, chris579, and Corak for pointing me back to the obvious things I should have not overlooked. I'm just starting to learn c# but this really taught me a good lesson for sure. thanks again all.